# Do reserved cards get returned when gold token is spent?

Tags: splendor

I am playing with my son and he reserves a card I wanted and gets a gold token. On his next turn he buys another card and uses the Gold token in his purchase.

What happens to the reserved card?  He now has no gold token, a card I want in reserve.

Does the reserved card get brought back in to the game?

Answer (score 6):

From the rules [here](https://www.spacecowboys.fr/img/games/splendor/details/rules/Rules_Splendor_US.pdf)

> The reserved cards are kept in hand and cannot be discarded.
>   Players may not have more than three reserved cards in hand,
>   and the only way to get rid of a card is to buy it (see below).

and

> To purchase a card, a player must spend the number of
>   tokens indicated on the card. A joker token can replace any
>   color. The spent tokens (including any jokers) are returned to
>   the middle of the table.
>   A player may purchase one of the face-up development
>   cards in the middle of the table or a card in his hand that was
>   reserved on a previous turn.

It's entirely legitimate to reserve a card another player might want as long as they don't exceed the 3 card hand limit.

The rules do NOT say they gold token has to be used to purchase the reserved card.  The rules make it clear a reserved card can not be discarded.  The rules state nothing rules about it returning to the stacks at any point.

Comment: In fact, it's possible to reserve a card even if there is no gold left

Comment: @ikwgami, That is true yes.  I left that out to try and keep answer to bare minimum rules quoting but adding that could have helped back up the point that you don't have to use the gold on a reserved card as you might not have taken any.

Answer (score -1):

The golden token is used to do two things. You use it to reserve a card (it might be one you or another player is saving up to get) and once you reserved a card in a future go you can use the token as any coloured token to buy a card.

The reserved card stays reserved until it is bought by the player.

Comment: The gold token isn't used to reserve the card. You can reserve a card even if they are no gold token left.